# Set aria-live to read updates before reading out the DOM element in focus

Tags: javascript, accessibility, wai-aria

Suppose you have a aria-live region and it is read out every time some change is made. But every time the change is made, the focus moves to a particular form element `First Name`.

If the text being updated in aria-live region is `Loading complete`, the preferred reading sequence is `Loading complete First name`, i.e. first the aria-live region and then the element being focused.

However, regardless of the politeness setting of aria-live, I can't seem to get that combination.

if `aria-live = assertive` or `aria-live = polite`, it reads `First name Loading complete`

if `aria-live = rude`, it only reads `Loading complete`, ignoring reading of the element being focused.

How do I make this  precedence order?

I am using JavaScript to manipulate the contents.

Comment: Do you really need to communicate the loading complete status to the user? What I have done in these instances is to construct the message such that the context of the aria-live announcement is unambiguous but it is best to avoid this use of it if possible as it is likely to lead to usability issues.

Also - changing the focus of a user automatically on input is normally considered an accessibility violation http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change.html

Comment: You should provide a jsfiddle example and give information on the screen reader you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced a very similar problem in the past. Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but a timeout helped me. So essentially the code looks like:

```
// ...
// perform updates to your live region
// ...
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.autofocus').focus();
});
```

ARIA has been a mystery to me, and still is, so can't really explain why this would work, but it did for me anyway.